# Make a struct member optional when initializing struct

Tags: solidity, web3js

```
struct Petition {
    uint id;
    string name;
    string description;
    uint voteFor;
    uint voteAgainst;
    address[] addressOfVotedForUsers;
    address[] addressOfVotedAgainstUsers;
    mapping(address=>bool) usersVotedFor;
    mapping(address=>bool) usersVotedAgainst;
}

function addPetition(string memory _name, string memory _desc) public {
    petitions[petitionCount] = Petition(petitionCount,_name,_desc,0,0); 
    petitionCount++; 
}

s/VoteCast.sol:42:34: TypeError: Wrong argument count for struct constructor: 5 arguments given but expected 7. Members that have to be skipped in memory: usersVotedAgainst usersVotedFor
  petitions[petitionCount] = Petition(petitionCount,_name,_desc,0,0);
```

I have a struct where I don't want the value of the address[] arrays to be intialised. But I get a error expected 7 arguments, instead got 5. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: There is nothing in this code that could possibly give this error!!!

Comment: Please add the code segment where you are trying to initialize this and getting error(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Petition {
    uint id;
    string name;
    string description;
    uint voteFor;
    uint voteAgainst;
    address[] addressOfVotedForUsers;
    address[] addressOfVotedAgainstUsers;
    mapping(address=>bool) usersVotedFor;
    mapping(address=>bool) usersVotedAgainst;
}

mapping(uint => Petition) public petitions;
uint petitionCount=0;

function addPetition(string memory _name, string memory _desc) public {
    address[] memory whatever;  //empty array
    petitions[petitionCount] = Petition(petitionCount, _name, _desc, 0, 0, whatever, whatever); 
    petitionCount++; 
}

function addPetition(string memory _name, string memory _desc, address[] memory x, address[] memory y) public {
    petitions[petitionCount] = Petition(petitionCount, _name, _desc, 0, 0, x, y); 
    petitionCount++; 
}
```